# Download a directory using curl

Tags: curl, bitbucket

I need to download list of files in a directory (from bitbucket repository), Can I use curl command to do?

Any suggestion please?

I have tried,

```
curl -O http://myportal/bitbucket/repoName/browse/directorName/
```

Throws error,

```
curl: Remote file name has no lenght!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to pass credentials to access the repo, you should be able to go to the source view for the file in question and then use the "open raw" link from Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or "raw file" from Bitbucket Server (the one you host yourself). (If you do need to pass credentials, then that's something else to build into your request.)

Note that the default "open raw" link in Bitbucket Cloud uses the commit hash - that's a permanent link to that specific version. If you'd rather use the head of a specific branch, then you can change the commit hash to the branch name. (As an example, if I go to https://bitbucket.org/mirror/linux and browse to the Makefile, the current link is to https://bitbucket.org/mirror/linux/raw/1d51b4b1d3f2db0d6d144175e31a84e472fbd99a/Makefile - but I can always go to https://bitbucket.org/mirror/linux/raw/master/Makefile to see the latest version of that file in the master branch.)

Comment: I need to download using curl

Comment: Please read my comment. I told you how to find a link suitable for use with curl.